# Error creating SharePoint list item that has fields which names start with underscore

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items
```

When attempting to create a SharePoint list item it fails with the following error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Field '_fieldExample' is not recognied",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "8b54a4a4-5f14-47d0-8651-908043a9aea1",
            "date": "2018-05-07T07:56:52"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example JSON reqeust body to reproduce the issue:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "Title": "Title42",
    "_fieldExample": "aaa"
   }
}
```

However the field "_fieldExample" is present in the list:

The JSON of the field:

```
{
    "columnGroup": "Custom Columns",
    "description": "",
    "displayName": "_fieldExample",
    "enforceUniqueValues": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "id": "18012342-6f36-44dd-a660-ca27d194cc79",
    "indexed": false,
    "name": "_fieldExample",
    "readOnly": false,
    "required": false,
    "text": {
        "allowMultipleLines": false,
        "appendChangesToExistingText": false,
        "linesForEditing": 0,
        "maxLength": 255
    }
}
```

I'm following the documentation from the following link:

```
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/listitem_create
```